# How to create a discrete representation of a distribution function?

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, sampling

I have a polynomial function representing a distribution function: $x^4 -6x^3 + 9x^2 ; 0 \le x \le 3$ but I need to get a discrete set of $ n $ data points representative of this distribution. I've seen there's many existing code libraries to do this for more standard distributions like binomial and normal, but is there a way I can do this for a given polynomial distribution function?

I had the idea of trying to divide the region into rectangles of equal area, then choosing one value from within each rectangle, but I would not know how to go about solving for each rectangle.

Comment: There are many solutions.  Please tell us what you want to use this "representation" for.  I would guess, from your last paragraph, it might be for computing the percentage point function, but other interpretations are possible.

Comment: My guess is that "many existing code libraries to do this for more standard distributions" you are referring to code like RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[$\mu,\; \sigma$], $n$]; (Mathematica). Please confirm that you are asking for a random variate generating algorithm. Also, @Ben.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to do that. Here is one example that is easy to understand but is not efficient in Mathematica code for n=1000,

```
testxall = {}; testyall = {}; n = 1;
 While[n <= 1000,
  testx = 3 RandomReal[];
  testy = 5.0625 RandomReal[];
  If[testy <= testx^4 - 6 testx^3 + 9 testx^2, 
   testxall = AppendTo[testxall, testx]; 
   testyall = AppendTo[testyall, testy]; n++]]
lp1 = ListPlot[Transpose[{testxall, testyall}]];
pl1 = Plot[{x^4 - 6 x^3 + 9 x^2, 5.0625}, {x, 0, 3}];
Show[pl1, lp1]
```

[image]

The answer you asked for is the testxall array. What this does is generate rectangular {x,y} coordinates, and only count those that are less than or equal to the function. Note that the density is more compact in the x direction than in the y direction, but that is irrelevant.

Another, more efficient, way is to randomly generate probabilities, and that would be rather more commonly used.

Comment: How does this answer the question?  What exactly is the **discrete representation** of the distribution that was requested?

Comment: @whuber The reason why I answered the way I did is because that is the way I interpreted the question based on personal experience, i.e., been there done that. Now you are perfectly correct that there is a degree of ambiguity in the question, but even given that I fail to see what a "discrete set of  data points" could be referring to if not how I interpreted the question. Missing is the word "random."

Comment: I agree with Carl that an IID random sample is one reasonable way you could interpret a "discrete representation" of a continuous distribution.  Another reasonable interpretation would be to give deterministic points $x_1,...,x_n$ satisfying $F(x_i) = \tfrac{2i-1}{2n}$ so that you are getting points that are evenly spaced quantiles.  Depending on what you want, one or the other could be better, but I would think that these are reasonable ideas of what people might like when they ask for a "discrete representation" of a continuous distribution.

Comment: @Ben Please see my note to the OP above. I did not consider a possible meaning for evenly spaced quantiles because it did not satisfy "existing code libraries" without stretching the meaning in a way that would be relatively improbable for a relative newbie. I think that it is problematic to ask someone relatively new to statistics to use exact formal language when they do not yet know that language well enough to do so. I get a lot of smiles when I fill in the blanks.